# What anime/manga is this girl wearing a red beret from?

Tags: merchandise

[image]

I wanna know who this character is for my friend.

Comment: Is there any more information you can add to this? Is there a maker's label on the base?

Comment: My friend brought it

Answer (score 8):

The female character in the above picture is [Tomomi Aizawa](http://myanimelist.net/character/32357/Tomomi_Aizawa) from [Pia Carrot e Youkoso!! 3](https://vndb.org/v2397).

> [image]

The visual novel does not currently have an anime adaptation. You can find the figurine [here](https://myanimeshelf.com/figures/78599_Aizawa_Tomomi_Paroparo_Type_Ver.).